# Extract image frame from video in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I trying to create media player in window form application us C#. I want to get thumbnails of video file in order to show them in the playing list, Can any body help me to figure out the code or refer me some links. i am really stuck at this point

Comment: Which plugin do you use to play media?